# 4 bit audio editor?

Tags: bit-depth, audio-editor, downsampling

I am working on an electronics project and I need to store speech data in an extremely limited memory. Since the microcontroller is not equipped to dynamically decompress audio data, I am stuck with having to use uncompressed audio.

After some experimentation I figured out that 4 bit audio sampled at 4000 Hz is enough to convey speech without being annoying. It takes 2000 bytes to store a second of audio, which is manageable if not perfect.

The problem here is that no audio editor I know of can output any lower than 8 bit audio at 8000 Hz.

I have tried using Nyquist prompt to quantize sound data to 4 bits and downsampling audio to 4000 Hz in Audacity. It sort of works, but I can still only export to 8 bit 8000 Hz PCM RAW. And even then, I found that the RAW binary still has full 8-bit data. There are hex values like 0x86, 0x7f all over the place where I would have expected all samples to have 0 in their lower 4 bits. Further, the Nyquist prompt output is full of high frequency noise. Filtering this noise with an equalization filter does filter the noise, but it also "de-quantizes" the audio. This is only logical, I guess, because the track is in 8 bit PCM and there is no way to tell audacity not to mess with the quantization.

**So, I am essentially looking for an audio editor that can work with 4 bits. It need not be as fully featured as the more famous ones, but as long as it can import 8-bit data and output 4-bit data after equalization, it will work. Also, it can be a command line tool, some abandoned open source project or anything as long as it does my job.**

I don't have a digital audio background, so I might not have asked this question properly or followed proper terminology, and I apologise for that.

Any general advice pertaining to this question/alternate methods/pointers in the right direction are welcome.

Comment: Hello. Notice that if your 8 to 4 bits conversion is successful, 1 byte of output will actually represent 2 samples, it is therefore not surprising that the lower 4 bits are not always equal to 0 (unless one sample out of two in your input data is equal to zero). How do you plan to implement digital to analog conversion of these audio data ?

Comment: @audionuma Even though the conversion done in software, it is still internally stored as 8 bit samples in audacity. And there is no option to export to 4 bit RAW PCM. The exported RAW should have 8 bit samples with zero for the lower 4 bits but it isn't working that way. Thats why I am looking for a audio editor where sound is internally handled as 4 bit.

Comment: @audionuma I intend to create a very minimal R-2R DAC to play the samples.

Comment: There is no such thing as an audio editor that handles audio internally as 4 bits. The most you can hope for is a DAW that will export a decimated audio 4 bit stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an already existing tool for your purpose. (At least, I couldn't find one). You might have to build your own tool in your language of choice.

Some basic building blocks could be :

Export your audio as unsigned 8 bits 8 kHz raw. Before exporting, apply a low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency below 2 kHz with a steep attenuation. That is to prevent aliasing when down-sampling to 4 kHz sampling rate.

Read data from the input file four bytes at a time. You get four bytes that represent four samples of the input audio signal `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`.

One way to down-sample is by [decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)). So you will only keep `b0`and `b2`.

The brutal way to reduce quantization (from 8 bits to 4 bits) is to use the right bit shifting operator (`>>`). This is not ideal, might cause some rounding errors, but that is worth trying. Another option would be to use [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) but that will not be covered here.

`qb0 = b0 >> 4
qb2 = b2 >> 4`

Now, you need to output these two quantized samples and save them in a file. It would be nice (as you are looking to save space) to code these two 4 bits samples into one byte. For this, you can use binary operators *AND* (`&`) and *OR* (`|`).

`out = (qb0 << 4) | qb2`

The four leftmost bits of `out` are one sample coded as unsigned four bits, the four rightmost bits of `out`are the next sample.

Both bits manipulation steps can be done as :

`out = (b0 & 0xF0) | (b2 >> 4)`

Corner case : depending on the input file size, your last read might only return 1, 2 or 3 valid bytes. If it's 3, just use the same process on `b0`and `b2`. Else, you must stuff the last output byte with zero :

`out = b0 & 0xF0`

Example

input file : `7F A2 C1 D8 E4`. That's 5 samples coded as unsigned int. (Spaces added for readability, they are not part of the input file).

Get 4 bytes `7F`, `A2`, `C1`, `D8`.

`7F & F0` -> `70`

`C1 >> 4` -> `0C`

`70 | 0C`-> `7C` that will be the first byte of the output file.

Get 4 bytes. Actually, there's only one left `D8`.

`D8 & F0`-> `D0` that will be the second byte of the output file.

The output file ends up like this : `7C D0`.

Comment: I did something like this too. I converted the raw into a comma separated list of hex data and wrote a simple c++ code to ignore every other sample and then mix the remaining ones. Since I had to embed the binary into a c code file, this approach was more preferable to what you suggested. It sort of works, but it results in an extremely noisy sound (even for 4 bit audio). That is what prompted me to search for a 4 bit audio editor.

Comment: If only there were some way to filter out the high frequencies from the final output file in this method you suggest, I would not need a dedicated 4 bit audio editor. If you know a way to do that (I suspect it has got something to do with fourier analysis for discrete samples) it would be awesome.

I am, however, very close to giving up and going with this noise-prone method. If no better answers come by in a few days, I will select this as the accepted answer because it (sort of) answers my question.

Comment: I do not clearly understand your workflow. If you insert the 8 bit / 8 kHz data as a C array in a header, you're not saving any space ? You mean that you then process this data at compile time so that only the quantized/down-sampled data is stored in the binary ? In any case, you have to low-pass the input data before down-sampling. This can be done in audacity before exporting the raw 8 bits / 8 kHz data.

Comment: No, the program that does the downsampling and bitcrushing outputs an array of bytes which I then copy into the main program (come on, I'm not that stupid). Sorry for being confusing.

Low pass before downsampling. Okay I will try that next (I was under the impression that decreasing the bit depth results in high frequency noise regardless of the original audio's max frequency.)

Comment: @KittyHawk I'm sorry if I gave the impression that I consider you are stupid. About the lowpass before downsampling, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Answer (score 1):

Dead post but answering for posterity!

Win Xp has a sound recorder which can convert wav to ADPCM 8khz-4bit mono file

You can  copy "sndrec32.exe" from xp to install on window 7.

Answer (score 0):

Awave Audio can convert to an ADPCM 4-bit 6kHz mono file, and it can export to several different formats.

Comment: Hi average Joe. Just to let you know, this was auto-flagged as a low quality answer because it lacks detail. It does seem to answer the question as it is, but if you could add a bit more detail, that would be fantastic. Also, Welcome! And please take the [Tour] and read [Ask]. Thanks Joe :)